# What are the key reasons for the performance improvements in 12.3?

Tags: system-performance, benchmarking, version-12.3

The built in benchmark test on my stationary workstation shows an improvement from 2.82 to 5.99, all other hardware and operating systems settings the same.

This looks very good. My question is: What are the key reasons/changes that has been done to the product?
I can't see the same improvement on my laptop.

[image]

Comment: Is it right that there are different computer name and OS?

Comment: No, it is the same computer. But in the benchmark today, the program decided to name otherwise - seems to be related to licensed processors (it is an 8 core processor i7-7820X)

Comment: ..and Windows10

Comment: Just for curiosity, I did a test on my MacBook Pro: for total score, v12.2 gives 2.78 while v12.3 gives 3.30. Besides, I also feel the operations related to `Dataset` are generally more performant on v12.3. Exciting!

Comment: The "4-node homogenous cluster" makes me suspicious of the benchmark - see this post (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235930/65858) and the comments below. It seems to indicate it is running on parallel kernels which artificially inflates the result.

Comment: I'm happy that some folks might be seeing a performance uptick with 12.3, but I wonder if this is tied to architecture.  I run Mathematica on an AMD Threadripper and my benchmarking results from v12.2 to 12.3 were 3.22 to 3.31, respectively.  Not earth shattering by any stretch.

Comment: @ala10 Good point that it is related to the architecture. But it is the same computer as last year. Maybe some of the compilation improvements makes better use of the available processors & threads. I will check the post you refer to .

Comment: @ala10 it seems like you are right. I haven't tried all variants yet but it seems like the result from Benchmark depends on whether you launch/close all Kernels first. Which makes more of a bug I think.

Answer (score 5):

In Jon McLoone's 12.3 overview video, https://www.twitch.tv/videos/1026952947?t=00h09m04s, he mentions that they used the new compiler machinery (FunctionCompile, etc.) on several built-in functions (he mentions e.g., EuclideanDistance being 1.5x faster, CoordinateBounds 3x faster, etc).